# How to Select number of classes and output?

Tags: javascript, jquery

New to js.

I want to be able to say if there are 2 classes on that page then insert another class but if there is 3 classes then insert a different class.

sometimes the page will be like...

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="compare"></div>
    <div class="compare"></div>
</div>
```

and sometimes the page might be

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="compare"></div>
    <div class="compare"></div>
    <div class="compare"></div>
</div>
```

and sometimes like

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="compare"></div>
    <div class="compare"></div>
    <div class="compare"></div>
    <div class="compare"></div>
</div>
```

I need to add a class to compare if the page display 2 classes of compare or add a different class if the page has 3 classes of compare

Thanks in advance
Ollie

Comment: You can check the `.length` of the result of `document.querySelectorAll(selector)`

Comment: Two elements with a specific class?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you did not seem to have tried it yourself. Im sorry.

Comment: Hello Jonas W. I don't know what you mean by trying it myself, been trying to work out this answer for the last 2 days!

Is there any scripts that would work?

Comment: how are you willing to add the 3th class? by clicking a button, when the page is loading, when the mouse hovers some component... please share a little bit of your code so will be easier to help you find a good answer

Comment: You should at least add a snipet of your code,your question is vague. we should not give that kind of help if the person who asks, he has not tried sth.

Comment: Question updated

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can do like this ( Assuming you are using it)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('.compare').length >=2 ) {
      //$('yourContainer').addClass('your-new-class');
      //add your code as per your need.
    }
});
```